# How can i push to an custom typed array

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

Im using Angular 5 with typescript 2.7.1.
In typescript i have a custom type

```
 arr: {id: string; name: string; }[];
```

and i want to push an element to the array, and have tried the following:

```
this.arr.push({id: "text", name: "text"})
```

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

```
let array2 : {id: "id", name: "name"}
this.arr.push(array2)
```

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

I don't understand why it wont work, I am defining id and name in push, I just want to add more elements to the array, am i missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initialize the array with an empty array before you use the field:

```
this.rows = [];
```

Or directly upon declaration

```
rows: {id: string; name: string; }[] = [];
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this myself and it wasn't initially clear to initialize the array. Once you do that, the array can accept objects of its type:

```
    type arr = {id: string, name: string}
    
    const array1: arr[] =[];
    const array2: arr = {id: "id", name: "name"}

    array1.push(array2);
    console.log(array1) // prints [{"id": "id","name": "name"}]
```

[Typescript Playground Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQ4FwTwBwU2BDATo4BeYBvAlgEwFzADOYiWAdgOYA0wZ8AtjAcaZQL4BQowXoAxgHsyxBMngQAjASSIA2gF00CgNy8Qg4WFGJxAJmnI0mXAQBEuUzTqMz1mKc5rt4iQDooAV0IALABQy9AEpVbg1CAQAbGFcIgQp-MUlA4AB6FOAoVjBCYFkMcxxTMwsqUzsi4DKGezZFIA)